# HDMI not working with nVidia drivers post upgrade to 21.04 from 20.04

Tags: upgrade, hdmi

After upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04 I do not have access anymore to my HDMI plugged in TV. The display menu does not show anymore Detect Displays nor allows me to select HDMI.
I did try many cables that used to work before, all ok with Win10.
Thanks for your help as I am stuck and not able to find a solution.

```
$ sudo lshw -C video

*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218M [GeForce 310M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory:d3400000-d37fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:e080(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: This maybe because the closed-source drivers aren't built for the 5.11 kernel used by 21.04, or something-else (20.04 uses 5.4 (GA) or 5.8 (HWE), 20.10 uses 5.8) but you've not provided any specifics as to what hardware and *drivers* you're talking about (only they are nVidia).  What is your video hardware? (`sudo lshw -C video` etc) and what *drivers* or kernel modules did you load? and from where?  (`ubuntu-drivers` or if not where?)

Comment: For what I did load, is all standard from installation, with later updates from the distribution.

Comment: I could not find any HDMI port constructor anywhere, si this must be something standard... nah?